# Adjugate matrix in octave

Tags: matrix, octave

is there any function in gnu octave that adjunge matrix (similar to adjoint in matlab etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let matrix A be n by n matrix.

If matrix is invertible then let B be adjoint matrix of A
B = inv(A)*det(A)

If matrix is not invertible then use this code to get the adjoint.
Calculate the cofactors of matrix A then tranpose them:

```
    function Adjoint_A = adjoint(A)
    
    %Of course it must be nxn matrix
    [n,m] = size(A);
    if n ~= m
        disp('This is not square matrix.')
        return
    endif
    
    Adjoint_A = zeros(n,m);
    
    % Arlright first we need to find the cofactor then tranpose the whole matrix. 
    for i = 1:m
        for j = 1:n
            %Getting minors
            minor_A = A;
            minor_A(i,:) = [];
            minor_A(:,j) = [];
            %Filling up the matrix with cofactor
            Adjoint_A(i,j) = ((-1)^(i+j))*det(minor_A);
        endfor
    endfor
    
    Adjoint_A = Adjoint_A';
    endfunction
```

Answer (score 9):

The adjugate is *probably* not what you actually want.

If you want the normal adjoint (the conjugate transpose), then `x'` will give it to you for `x`.  (The non-conjugated transpose is `x.'`, or `transpose(x)`.  `conj(x)` gives the complex conjugate, and works on matrices and vectors as well.)

If you actually want the [adjugate (aka classical adjoint)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), I don't believe Octave has it built in.  There are a few ways to calculate this.  If you can assume invertibility, then it's just `det(x)*inv(x)`.  If not, it's a bit more complicated.  In general, the adjugate is the transpose of the cofactor matrix.  The cofactor matrix replaces each element in the original matrix with its cofactor (plus or minus its minor, which is the determinant of the original matrix without that row and column.  The plus or minus rule is the same for determinant expansion -- if the sum of the row and column is even, it's positive, if negative, it's odd).

The simplest codewise is probably to use the SVD (which is built-in) -- the adjugate is an antihomomorphism with adj(xy) = adj(y) adj(x).  The SVD of x is a set of matrices u,s,v, with u*s*v' = x, s diagonal, u and v both unitary.  adj(x) = adj(u*s*v') = adj(v')adj(s)adj(u).  For invertible matrices, the adjugate is just the determinant times the inverse.  For unitary matrices, this is just the conjugate transpose.  adj(x) = det(v') v adj(s) det(u) u' = det(v'*u) v adj(s) u'.  The adjugate of a diagonal matrix s is relatively easy to calculate -- each entry off the diagonal is zero, and each entry on the diagonal is the product of the others.

Comment: What I wanted was to adjugate matrix and det(x)*inv(x) is a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After some tries I calculated the co-factors using the following command:

```matlab
det(a)*inv(a).'
```

note the dots in the end are part of the command

Comment: Does not work with `.'` included, atleast not for my purposes

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no bulit in function for adj in octave you can try, det(A) * inv(A)... however there is no actually bulit in func, you can also try finding cofactor of the matrix and then transpose it. Also does it say you have to use matLab?? https://www.dcode.fr/adjoint-matrix works for me as well....